# select query where in clause problem in spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

public class CountryMasterModel {
private String countryNames[];

```
public String[] getCountryNames() {
    return countryNames;
}

public void setCountryNames(String[] countryNames) {
    this.countryNames = countryNames;
}
```

}

public interface CountryMasterService {

```
List<String> getCountryData(String compCode, CountryMasterModel model) throws SQLException, DataAccessException;
```

}

@Component
public class CountryMasterDAO implements CountryMasterService{

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate template;

@Override
public List<String> getCountryData(CountryMasterModel model) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
    this.template = new JdbcTemplate(DBMSSQL.getDBCon());
    System.out.println(template.getDataSource().getConnection().getCatalog());
    List<String> ids = Arrays.asList(model.getCountryNames());
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("countryName", ids);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list = this.template.query("SELECT NAME FROM country_master WHERE NAME IN (?)", new Object[] { ids },
            new CountryMasterResultSetExtrator());
    System.out.println("ids = " + ids);
    System.out.println("list = " + list.get(0));
    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws DataAccessException, SQLException {
    CountryMasterModel bean = new CountryMasterModel();
    String a[] = { "India", "Pakistan", "Russia", "America",};
    bean.setCountryNames(a);
    System.out.println(StringUtil.getStringArray(a));
    List<String> list = new CountryMasterDAO().getCountryData(bean);
    System.out.println("List Size = "+list.size());
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo3fG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

```
list = this.template.query(
          "SELECT NAME FROM country_master WHERE NAME IN (?)", 
           new Object[] { ids },
            new CountryMasterResultSetExtrator()
       );
```

`NAME IN (?)` is requiring one param and `new Object[] { ids }` has 3 params. try this`NAME IN (?,?,?)`

check this link for more information:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-in-list

Comment: Dynamic data will come then how to give question mark. 
For testing, I only took three country names.

Comment: did you check the examples on link?

Comment: Yes checked. An example is given in 2.2. did not work on exception arrives.

Comment: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT NAME FROM country_master WHERE NAME IN (?)]; SQL state [null];

Comment: error code [0]; The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.;

Comment: nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.

Comment: this exception comes